# Transforming a string referenced by a pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I was learning about iterators and decided to use one by iterating through a vector of strings and transforming them to lowercase. In doing so I have come to a point where I can't figure out what is wrong. Here is the code I have been using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"AbBBBcCc", "AFFDDsDCc"};

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::transform(*it->begin(), *it->end(), *it->begin(),
                       [](char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I was first trying to figure this out, there were a ton of errors. The only error I am getting now is:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')
 4298 |  *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
```

I can't figure out how to fix it. I got it to work by dereferencing the pointer to a regular string variable and replacing the pointer calls in the transform function with the variable. I know this is far from the best way to do this, but I am just wondering exactly why this code isn't working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::transform(*it->begin(), *it->end(), *it->begin(),
```

`it` here is iterating over `std::string`s in a vector, and is referencing some string in the vector.. Its `->` overload resolves to the string the iterator is currently references. Therefore:

```
it->begin()
```

invokes `std::string::begin()`, which returns an iterator to the beginning of the string, to its first character. Therefore

```
*it->begin()
```

Gives you the first character in the string, and `*it->end()` is, of course, undefined behavior. Derefencing an ending iterator value is always undefined behavior, so the expression "`*it->end()`" should give you pause, and give you some food for thought, on its own merits. You obviously meant to do:

```
  std::transform(it->begin(), it->end(), it->begin(),
                   [](char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works -

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

char* lower(char c){

}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"AbBBBcCc", "AFFDDsDCc"};

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    { std::string data=*it;
        std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
        std::cout << data<< std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above will probably be easiest to understand, although you can do it your way as well -

```
std::transform(it->begin(), it->end(), it->begin(), [](char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
```

There's another way as well if you are wishing to deterrence the pointer by using `*` and then convert it to lower case -

```
std::transform((*it).begin(), (*it).end(), (*it).begin(),
                       [](char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

All three of the code snippets I have above accomplishes the same task. The different examples above will help you understand working of pointers and dereferencing. Hope this helps